# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 139390: invalid continuation byte when scraping from Twitter API

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, twitter, utf-8

I have a web-scraper built using the python package tweepy and I always use it to gather tweets for research. Suddenly, it doesn't seem to work anymore. The issue is it can no longer decode all the characters?

```
# open and create a file to append the data to
csvFile = open('tweets.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
    # use the csv file
    # loop through the tweets variable and add contents to the CSV file
for tweet in tweets:
    text = tweet.full_text.strip()
    #convert the text to ascii ignoring all unicode characters, eg. emojis
    text_ascii = text.encode('ascii','ignore').decode()
    #split the text on whitespace and newlines into a list of words
    text_list = text_ascii.split()
    #iterate over the words, removing @ mentions or URLs 
    text_list_filtered = [word for word in text_list if not (word.startswith('@') or word.startswith('http'))]
    #join the list back into a string
    text_filtered = ' '.join(text_list_filtered)
    #decoding html escaped characters
    text_filtered = html.unescape(text_filtered)
    #write text to the CSV file
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.place, text_filtered])
    print(tweet.created_at, tweet.place, text_filtered)
csvFile.close()
```

so when I try to read it as a pandas dataframe I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 139390: invalid continuation byte
```

The line that is giving me the error is this:

```
tweetsdf = pd.read_csv('tweets.csv')
```

I have tried to change the following bit of code from this:

```
text_ascii = text.encode('ascii','ignore').decode()
```

to this:

```
text_ascii = text.encode('utf-8','ignore').decode()
```

But then I get the same problem when I try to collect the tweets from the API. What should I do?

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: If its the pandas df that is giving you the issue, try reading it with encoding = "ISO-8859-1"

Comment: Not sure how you are getting an E1 byte in your file if only writing ASCII.  Debug down to a single tweet written to the file that causes the error and make a [mcve]

Comment: I edited the original post to show what line is giving me the error.

Comment: I tried reading it with encoding "ISO-8859-1" (see changes in original post) and I still receive the same UniCodeDecodeError

Comment: The E1 byte seems to be caused by the fact that for some tweets, the code prints the location where the tweet was posted. After removing 'tweet.place' from " csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.place, text_filtered])", the error disappeared and I was able to read the csv file into a pandas dataframe again.

Answer (score 0):

The E1 byte seems to be caused by the fact that for some tweets, the code prints the location where the tweet was posted. After removing '`tweet.place`' from " `csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.place, text_filtered])`", the error disappeared and I was able to read the csv file into a pandas dataframe again.